# discord py command not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord bot, and trying to have / menu context commands. this is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
load_dotenv()
url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/ID/commands"
TOKEN = "TOKEN"


# This is an example CHAT_INPUT or Slash Command, with a type of 1
json = {
    "name": "ping",
    "type": 1,
    "description": "test lmao",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "type": 3,
            "required": True,
        }
    ]
}

# For authorization, you can use either your bot token

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bot TOKEN"
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/',intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_read():
  print("Bot is ready!")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def ping(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send("Pong! "+ str(arg))



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The application command shows up, but the bot doesn't respond and I get this error:
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'ping' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you try to use slash commands, but you aren’t defining any app commands (slash commands) you‘re defining a text command.

to you slash commands, you should use the app_commands package of discord.py. it also handles registering the app commands at discord

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#application-commands

Comment: thank you, but I think i'm going to use a simpler third party package :)

Comment: @Takeraparterer Consider not using a third party package, it's really easy the built-in way. In this post you just decided to send raw API requests instead of using the library, which is unnecessarily difficult. You don't need any of this JSON data, and you don't need to send any API requests. Discord.py handles all that for you.

Comment: @stijndcl how? the docs are confusing to me. would you mind providing a simple example?

Comment: NVM I solved it